# Force avprobe format detection

Tags: libav, gif

I have a gif file without an extention called `loop`.

the command `avprobe loop` returns:

`[mp3 @ 0x7faa59004a00] Format detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!`

avprobe subsequently incorrectly recognises the format as being `mp3`.

How can I force avprobe to recognise the file format?

`avprobe -f gif loop` returns:

`Unknown input format: gif`

but `avprobe -formats | grep gif` returns:

`E gif    GIF Animation`

Version:

`avprobe version 11, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Nov 27 2014 11:02:18 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
avprobe 11
libavutil     54.  3. 0 / 54.  3. 0
libavcodec    56.  1. 0 / 56.  1. 0
libavformat   56.  1. 0 / 56.  1. 0
libavdevice   55.  0. 0 / 55.  0. 0
libavfilter    5.  0. 0 /  5.  0. 0
libavresample  2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
libswscale     3.  0. 0 /  3.  0. 0`

Comment: Why not add an extension?

Comment: The file is temporarily created by a ruby gem I'm using (paperclip). I'd rather not override the default gem especially as this should be possible according to the avprobe documentation.